# Are there necessarily positive and negative points to this function?

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f$ be a non-zero continous function such that $\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)\cdot\sin(x)dx=0$. Does there exist $x_{1},x_{2} \in \left[0,\pi\right]$ such that $f\left(x_{1}\right)\cdot f\left(x_{2}\right)<0$?

Comment: the function can be zero but its not the "zero function"

Comment: Try to prove by contradiction. What happens if $f(x)\gt 0$ or $f(x)\lt 0$ for all $x\in[0,\pi]$?

Comment: If you don't assume $f$ continuous, wouldn't $f(x)=\mathbb{1}_{[0,\pi /2]}- \mathbb{1}_{]\pi /2,\pi]}$ be a good example ?

Comment: @Tavish what we happn? the function will be positive?

Comment: @Fabien I write that its continuous

Comment: Yes, so $f(x)\sin x$ is also positive, which means $\int f(x)\sin x \ dx$ is too.

Comment: @Tavish but the integral is \in[0,\pi]

Comment: Yes, that’s why $f(x)\sin x\gt 0$.

Comment: is there a way to solve it with innerproduct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.

To prove this, let’s argue *by contradiction*.
Assume that there do not exist $x_1, x_2 \in [0,\pi]$ s.t. $f(x_1) f(x_2) < 0$; since $f$ is continuous, this means that either $f(x) \geq 0$ or $f(x) \leq 0$ in $[0,\pi]$.
 Therefore you have either $f(x) \sin x \geq 0$ or $f(x) \sin x\leq 0$ in $[0,\pi]$, because $\sin x \geq 0$ in $[0,\pi]$ (and $\sin x =0$ iff $x=0,\pi$).
Now, in either case condition $\int_0^\pi f(x) \sin x\ \text{d} x =0$ entails $f(x) \sin x = 0$ in $[0,\pi]$ and, since $\sin x >0$ in $]0,\pi[$, this in turn implies $f(x) = 0$ in $]0,\pi[$; but then $f(x) =0$ everywhere in $[0,\pi]$ by continuity. **Contradiction!**

Comment: thank you very much!